# How to log info from PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, powershell

So I have a PowerShell script which has a log defined and calls another powershell function: (example below)

```
Start-Transcript -path ".\ExampleLog.txt"
.\GetDataFromDatabase.ps1
Stop-Transcript
```

When I call `.\GetDataFromDatabase.ps1`, it doesn't log anything printed out by the script, despite it appearing in the PowerShell window.

If I save the output from the script and echo it:

```
$x = .\GetDataFromDatabase.ps1
echo $x
```

It only logs the result of the script (e.g "COPY 102304"), and no info that was printed by the PostgreSQL function to the command window.

How can I make sure the info raised inside the postgres function is logged?

Comment: Are you using Write-Host in your GetDataFromDatabase script? http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/

Comment: See also Keith's blog post here: https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/effective-powershell-item-14-capturing-all-output-from-a-script/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DavidBrabant mentioned, `GetDataFromDatabase.ps1` is most likely writing status output to the host console. Host output normally can't be captured as it doesn't go to the regular [output streams](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/). To get around this you need to somehow mangle host output into one of the other streams. To my knowledge the only way to achieve this is to run the script in a separate `powershell` process. That way the host output of the child process goes into the success output stream of the parent process:

```
Start-Transcript -path ".\ExampleLog.txt"
powershell.exe -File .\GetDataFromDatabase.ps1
Stop-Transcript
```

Beware that there are side effects with this approach. For instance, other streams are mangled the same way, i.e. verbose, debug, and warning output goes to the success output stream of the parent process too. Only error output goes to the error output stream. Also, `$*Preference` settings of the parent aren't inherited by the child process.

For further help you need to show the content of `GetDataFromDatabase.ps1`.

Comment: Thanks heaps, running the separate Powershell process worked! Thankfully the side effects are not an issue for this particular project.